# Connectivity to internet with two WiFi adaptors

Tags: pi-3, networking, linux, kali

I am using Rasberry Pi with Kali Linux.

I have two WiFi adapter one (internal).

I am using for headless mode connection to my phone and other (external).

I am using for connectivity to internet to by connecting it to some WiFi hotspot and when I am trying to install or update something by `apt-get` but it sticks at 0% and shows cannot fetch data from http.kali.org

I am able to ping google.com, also I am able to access internet through firefox (by vnc server).

This problem was not there when I was having only one WiFi adaptor (internal) I.e. for headless mode through my phone and used mobile data for internet.

How to resolve it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kali Linux but in general I don't understand for what do you use both WiFi interfaces. Do you connect to two different hotspots? Both hotspots have internet access?

Comment: One I am using for headless connection and other for accessing internet

Comment: I still don't understand. With one interface you connect to an uplink WiFi internet router on your network and the other interface on the RasPi is connected to what? Also to the internet router? Or is there another remote WiFi hotspot? Or do you have a 4G modem on one interface to connect to the internet? Or do you have an access point running on the RasPi? Can you please provide a diagram what is connected to what? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise it may be possible that I don't see your reply.